# A British comedy movie from 1997-2005 about transporting sperm

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a British comedy movie that I watched a while ago. The theme was, an old mob boss who's at prison was trying to have a baby boy with his girlfriend by artificial insemination because he wanted an heir.

Every month he was sending his semen in a little bottle to his girlfriend by giving it to his men, and his girlfriend would inject that into herself when she's on her period. Since they've a little time to do this process, they've never been successful yet.

The mob boss was getting older and losing his androgens. An untalented boxer who loses almost every game and his friend (one of the mob members) were volunteered for transport that little bottle full of with semen to his girlfriend because they needed money. He was living with his wife/girlfriend and she always supported him no matter what.

He was white, tall, between 25-35, short haired with light beard. His friend was white, medium sized, had colored blonde-black hair with big sunglasses and middle aged. His girlfriend was white, blonde, short and between 25-35 aged.

I don't remember how but they lost the bottle in somehow. After that they found a solution which is fill a bottle with their own semens! Meantime some other guys found out that they've lost the bottle and they also did the same thing and went to the girlfriend's house.

The mob boss's girlfriend looked at the all bottles and selected the most loaded bottle. She was tall, blonde and young. At that moment my electricity has gone and I couldn't watch the rest!

It was made in between late 90s and early 00s. It was a low budget movie, probably rated 5-7.

Comment: You seem to have various different unregistered accounts. In order to use the site to its fullest and have full control of your previous post, including being able to comment, edit and accept any possible answers, you might want to register one of your accounts and then merge all the existing ones into it by following the [procedure described in the help center](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like the UK crime comedy [Baby Juice Express](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0295181/combined) (I kid you not) from 2004. From [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Baby-Juice-Express-Nick-Moran/dp/B0001MIRCK):

> Des (Nick Moran) is a middle-class lad living in Bognor with his sensible girlfriend Laura (Lisa Faulkner). [Failed boxer] Des dreams of being a gangster while his geezer mate Frank (Phil Davis) is a hopeless, tale-spinning petty criminal always dragging him into dodgy scams. [...]
>
> With the pair in debt to a local criminal, Frank hatches a plot to hijack the Baby Juice Express. A major crime boss who is serving time in prison is smuggling his sperm out via a chain of delivery - The "Express" - to his wife (Samantha Janus) so that she can conceive a child and save his fortune.
> After taking the sperm hostage with the help of Laura and posh black pal Sean (Paterson Joseph), Frank and Des plan to demand the sum of their debt as a ransom but the pair have to contend with man-mountain Terry Palooka (Joe Bugner), a hapless Welsh hitman and two gay henchmen (one of whom is Julian Clary, sans makeup).

Here's the poster, which I *think* is safe enough to show here but not taking any chances:

> [[image]

Comment: Yes , this is it . Thank you for your help . I can't mark as correct but this is the right answer .

Comment: Please see Napoleon's comment under your question about merging your accounts.